# jquery-UI Datepicker when on a div doesnt translate automatically

Tags: jquery-ui, localization, jquery-ui-datepicker

When I load my page the datepicker on my div always show in english, I have to click it to show in other language, as you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bFHxf/

If you change from div to input there is no problem with it since you have to click it to show... is this some kind of feature or bug?

Any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrapped your code in the `$(document).ready()` function and that seems to take care of the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/qtNyr/

Hope that helps!

Comment: tks alot, that was it. im still getting into jquery, tks!

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are initializing the datepicker too early.

If you wait until the document is loaded, it should work.  You can do this by surrounding the existing JavaScript code with

```
$(function() { existing code goes here });
```

So the result might look like:

```
$(function(){
$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "nl" ] );
$('#date').datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy'
        });
​})​
```

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JhcmJ/)